# Restoring login account blocked by inactivity

Tags: linux, user-accounts

Login accounts have an inactivity timer set at 35 days. That is, /etc/pam.d/passwd-auth has a line

```
auth        required      pam_lastlog.so inactive=35
```

So I get lines like

```
sshd[29629]: pam_unix(sshd:account): account weaverw has expired (failed to change password)
sshd[29629]: pam_lastlog(sshd:account): user weaverw inactive for 71 days - denied
```

Question: what is the best way to re-activate these accounts?  What the SA's have been doing is su over to the account, then exit, so it will have an entry in lastlog, but this seems inelegant.

Comment: man chage, you need to change the expired date.

Comment: I don't think that helps.  While the password was indeed expired, the real problem was the lastlog inactivity timer being hit.  IFAIK, chage will manipulate /etc/shadow, but won't affect lastlog and that countdown.

Answer (score 1):

To fix the `pam_unix` password expiration, edit `/etc/shadow`.  It has the format [colon separated fields]:

`username:passwd:number_of_days_since_pw_changed:...`

and set the 3rd field to zero.

---

To fix the `pam_lastlog` it's a bit uglier.  The control file is `/var/log/lastlog`.  It's a compressed and/or binary format file.

It can be *viewed* with the `lastlog` utility.  But [AFAICT] the utility provides no mechanism to change an individual entry.

It seems the recommended method is to null out the file.  While this changes it for all users, this is less severe than the passwd expiry changes. `cp /dev/null /var/log/lastlog` will do this without disturbing the `selinux` permissions.

The `usermod` utility *will* reset the information for a *single* user but *only* when using the `-u` option to change the user's uid.  Perhaps, used in conjunction with `-o`:

```
usermod -o -u <current_uid_of_user> <username>
```

At worst, do it in two commands, first setting uid to new unique uid, then set it back to the old one.  For example, if the user's uid was 5001 and there was *no* uid 5500 in use, do:

```
usermod -u 5500 fred
usermod -u 5001 fred
```

---

If you *really* want to preserve most information in `/var/log/lastlog` and the above doesn't work, the `shadow-utils` source package has a way to do it ...

Here's the source snippet from useradd:

```
static void lastlog_reset (uid_t uid)
{
    struct lastlog ll;
    int fd;
    off_t offset_uid = (off_t) (sizeof ll) * uid;

    if (access (LASTLOG_FILE, F_OK) != 0) {
        return;
    }

    memzero (&ll, sizeof (ll));

    fd = open (LASTLOG_FILE, O_RDWR);
    if (   (-1 == fd)
        || (lseek (fd, offset_uid, SEEK_SET) != offset_uid)
        || (write (fd, &ll, sizeof (ll)) != (ssize_t) sizeof (ll))
        || (fsync (fd) != 0)
        || (close (fd) != 0)) {
        fprintf (stderr,
                 _("%s: failed to reset the lastlog entry of UID %lu: %s\n"),
                 Prog, (unsigned long) uid, strerror (errno));
        SYSLOG ((LOG_WARN, "failed to reset the lastlog entry of UID %lu", (unsigned long) uid));
        /* continue */
    }
}
```

Here's a snippet from usermod:

```
/*
 * update_lastlog - update the lastlog file
 *
 * Relocate the "lastlog" entries for the user. The old entry is
 * left alone in case the UID was shared. It doesn't hurt anything
 * to just leave it be.
 */
static void update_lastlog (void)
{
    struct lastlog ll;
    int fd;
    off_t off_uid = (off_t) user_id * sizeof ll;
    off_t off_newuid = (off_t) user_newid * sizeof ll;

    if (access (LASTLOG_FILE, F_OK) != 0) {
        return;
    }

    fd = open (LASTLOG_FILE, O_RDWR);

    if (-1 == fd) {
        fprintf (stderr,
                 _("%s: failed to copy the lastlog entry of user %lu to user %lu: %s\n"),
                 Prog, (unsigned long) user_id, (unsigned long) user_newid, strerror (errno));
        return;
    }

    if (   (lseek (fd, off_uid, SEEK_SET) == off_uid)
        && (read (fd, &ll, sizeof ll) == (ssize_t) sizeof ll)) {
        /* Copy the old entry to its new location */
        if (   (lseek (fd, off_newuid, SEEK_SET) != off_newuid)
            || (write (fd, &ll, sizeof ll) != (ssize_t) sizeof ll)
            || (fsync (fd) != 0)
            || (close (fd) != 0)) {
            fprintf (stderr,
                     _("%s: failed to copy the lastlog entry of user %lu to user %lu: %s\n"),
                     Prog, (unsigned long) user_id, (unsigned long) user_newid, strerror (errno));
        }
    } else {
        /* Assume lseek or read failed because there is
         * no entry for the old UID */

        /* Check if the new UID already has an entry */
        if (   (lseek (fd, off_newuid, SEEK_SET) == off_newuid)
            && (read (fd, &ll, sizeof ll) == (ssize_t) sizeof ll)) {
            /* Reset the new uid's lastlog entry */
            memzero (&ll, sizeof (ll));
            if (   (lseek (fd, off_newuid, SEEK_SET) != off_newuid)
                || (write (fd, &ll, sizeof ll) != (ssize_t) sizeof ll)
                || (fsync (fd) != 0)
                || (close (fd) != 0)) {
                fprintf (stderr,
                         _("%s: failed to copy the lastlog entry of user %lu to user %lu: %s\n"),
                         Prog, (unsigned long) user_id, (unsigned long) user_newid, strerror (errno));
            }
        } else {
            (void) close (fd);
        }
    }
}
```

The definition for `struct lastlog` comes from `#include <lastlog.h>` and will look like:

```
/* The structure describing an entry in the database of
   previous logins.  */
struct lastlog
  {
#ifdef __WORDSIZE_TIME64_COMPAT32
    int32_t ll_time;
#else
    __time_t ll_time;
#endif
    char ll_line[UT_LINESIZE];
    char ll_host[UT_HOSTSIZE];
  };
```

Comment: I think this provides a complete answer.  It notes that to solve this, you must update the database in /var/log/lastlog.  It does suggest a way to do this without logging in as the user (although I couldn't get that to work) and provides detailed code if one wanted to build something to do it.  I'm going to rethink the elegance or lack thereof of the existing SA's approach.

Answer (score -2):

If you can get to the server as another user you can 'su - *user*' to reset the login time.

Comment: Welcome to ServerFault.  Isn't that what the OP said he was already doing that he considered inelegant?